# orgmode agenda view: use not only org-agenda-files, but also predefined buffers

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The `org-agenda-list` function produces a view from the files returned by `org-agenda-files`.
Is it possible to include additional active buffer(s), not files?

My idea is that I use an external tool, make a call with `start-process` and the output is redirected to a named buffer, and the buffer would be automatically included into agenda. The tool serves as data conversion/integration tool and output from it is org-mode compatible.
I'l like to keep the output in memory (a buffer) and don't save to the file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box.

Comment: One idea would be to save the buffers to temporary files, let-bind `org-agenda-files` to the locations of your temporary files, run your `org-agenda-list`, and then cleanup whatever needs cleaning; e.g., disposing of temporary files, unless it is a okay to keep them there; e.g., some OS cleaning out certain temporary files when the computer is turned-off/on.